# nginx rewrite all wildcard subdomains to www.site.com

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect all subdomains of http://abc.example.com to https://abc.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

This could work for `example.com` to `www.example.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

From `http` to `https` for all subdomains:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Notice the `server_name *.example.com`

You could also use `$server_name`

- **$host** – The hostname provided by the client for the current request.
- **$server_name** – The first hostname from the hostname declaration in your config for the server block that responds to the request.

### Canonical hostname

If the hostname doesn’t match the first name in the server_name list. Makes sure your content is only available at the canonical hostname, e.g. to avoid duplicate content issues ([SEO](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content)). Excellent for redirecting non-www to www or redirecting www to non-www in Nginx as long as your server block is only for a single website.

```
server_name example.com www.example.com example.net www.example.net _;
if ( $host != $server_name ) {
  return 301 $scheme://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Check this site [nginx-redirect](https://www.bjornjohansen.no/nginx-redirect) for extended version

Comment: I replaced  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;  instead of  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;  ...  now working good

Comment: I updated the answer to give more context hope it can helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen  443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name *.example.com;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```